# Release management with a distributed version control system

Tags: controls, version, distributed, dvcs

We're considering a switch from SVN to a distributed VCS at my workplace.

I'm familiar with all the reasons for wanting to use a DVCS for day-to-day development: local version control, easier branching and merging, etc., but I haven't seen that much that's compelling in terms of managing software releases.  Here's our release process:

- Discover what changes are available for merging.
- Run a query to find the defects/tickets associated with these changes.
- Filter out changes associated with "open" tickets. In our environment, tickets must be in a closed state in order to merged with a release branch.
- Filter out changes we don't want in the release branch.  We are very conservative when it comes to merging changes.  If a change isn't absolutely necessary, it doesn't get merged.
- Merge available changes, preferably in chronological order.  We group changes together if they're associated with the same ticket.
- Block unwanted changes from the release branch (`svnmerge block`) so we don't have to deal with them again.

Sometimes we can be juggling 3-5 different milestones at a time.  Some milestones have very different constraints, and the block list can get quite long.

I've been messing around with git, mercurial and plastic, and as far as I can tell none of them address this model very well.  It seems like they would work very well when you have only one product you're releasing, but I can't imagine using them for juggling multiple, very different products from the same codebase.

For example, cherry-picking seems to be an afterthought in mercurial.  (You have to use the 'transplant' extension, which is disabled by default).  After you cherry-pick a change into a branch it still shows up as an available integration.  Cherry-picking breaks the mercurial way of working.

DVCS seems to be better suited for feature branches.  There's no need for cherry-picking if you merge directly from a feature branch to trunk *and* the release branch.  But who wants to do all that merging all the time?  And how do you query for what's available to merge?  And how do you make sure all the changes in a feature branch belong together?  It sounds like total chaos.

I'm torn because the coder in me wants DVCS for day-to-day work.  I really want it.  But I fear the day when I have to put the release manager hat and sort out what needs to be merged and what doesn't.  I want to write code, I don't want to be a merge monkey.

Answer (score 2):

You really want to be using git in this situation, because it is so vastly superior when it comes to merging and release management.  Git allows for a signoff process for changes to go to release; it actually provides support for multiple layers of release management, precisely because that is how Linux is managed.

Simply put each release in a branch.  Instead of blocking out changes you don't want, accept only those that you do, by only signing off for release those changes that are going into a release.

Git also allows you to cherry-pick a collection of changes into a single patch to be sent upstream, so you don't have to carry all the 'oops, that didn't quite work' patches into the release branch or repository, only nice clean feature or fix patches.

Comment: > Simply put each release in a branch. Instead of blocking out changes you don't want, accept only those that you do, by only signing off for release those changes that are going into a release.

I've read this before but I can't make sense of how we would apply this.  In our workflow, when a change has made it to the trunk it's a "good" change.  It's been signed-off already.  What we're merging/blocking are appropriate/inappropriate changes from specific release branches.  I.e., change XYZ is desirable for Product A, but undesirable for Product B.